# fine-uploader - how use table as file list?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

For example, i have this init code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4" for="fine-uploader">Upload</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="fine-uploader">
        <div id="select-files"></div>
        <table>
            <tbody id="list-files">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ok, i have

1. `#fine-uploader` where i init fine-upload
2. `#select-files` where i init upload btn
3. `#list-files` where will be putting upload files

Ok, go

```
$(function(){
    var fine_uploader = $("#fine-uploader");

    var keyword_upload = fine_uploader.find("#select-files").fineUploader({
        listElement: fine_uploader.find('#list-files'),
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: '/fineuploader',
        },
    });
});
```

And this template

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
  <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
      <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
      <div>Upload a file</div>
    </div>
    <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
      <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
      <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
      <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
          <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
        <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>
        <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
        <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
        <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
        <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
        <a class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry" href="#">Retry</a>
        <a class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
        <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </span>
  </div>
</script>
```

And while this code output nothing?.. Just one `upload` button..

How i can create file list output in table ? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML table is not valid as it stands.  Generally speaking, if you want a table layout, you should style the template/HTML with CSS appropriately (display: table, etc), instead of using a `<table>`.  The templating code internal to Fine Uploader may not work with traditional HTML table elements.

If there is a specific reason why a table element is most appropriate or needed for your situation, let's discuss in [the GitHub issue you opened in the project's repo](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1246).